# Making wordpress multisite and working on the same content database

Tags: database, wordpress, social-networking, multilingual, multisite

I’ll try to make a website in 5 languages that two of them is LTR and others is RTL, I wanna all of them work on the same content database, I used WordPress Network sites, but only users table is shared among all sites on the network, I wanna make all tables share into all sites on the network.

Comment: Consider using of WPML plugin. With it, you don't need multisite for any number of languages.

Comment: thanks for you, with WPML plugin, Can I use a different theme? for each language!

Comment: No, in general, you cannot. There are some plugins for switching themes, but I don't know how do they work together with WPML. And in your question there were no word "theme" at all.

Comment: Thank you – KAGG Design, WPML is fixed my problem,